# How can I improve this sum with reduce method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sum, reduce

I would like to improve this sum using the `reduce` method, but I saw that works well for summing but also I have to do a subtract:

```
final = 0
@status.each do |data|
  final = final + data['pending_increase'] - data['pending_decrease']
end
```

The method I want to use is [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@status.reduce(0){|sum, data| sum + data['pending_increase'] - data['pending_decrease']}
```

or

```
@status.map{|data| data['pending_increase'] - data['pending_decrease']}.reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfect!, just a quicly question... why the zero in reduce(0)?

Comment: @BrianStanley: Well, because on the first iteration `sum` should be `0`.

Comment: @potashin The equal sign in your first snippet isn't necessary.

Comment: The assignment is superfluous, you can just use `+` instead of `+=`

Answer (score 2):

This will work too (as the initial seed is `0`), but doesn't use `reduce` as requested

```
@status.sum{|data| data['pending_increase'] - data['pending_decrease']}
```

This two expressions are equivalent, being `sum` shorter and simpler than `map`/`reduce`

```
enum.sum{...} == enum.map{...}.reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) uses `inject` aka `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a rails application, you can just do this:

```
@status.map{|data| data['pending_increase'] - data['pending_decrease']}.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first compute the differences, then sum them:

```
@status.map { |data| data['pending_increase'] - data['pending_decrease'] }.reduce(:+)
```

but this has the disadvantage of creating a temporary array.

Just sayin'.